# На Zyxel Keenetic Giga II не доступно для изменения поле Канал на вкладке WIFi

Tags: wifi, router

[image]Как разблокировать и выбрать канал wifi? Поле канал read-only. Страна выбрана Российская федерация

[image]/2Czss.jpg

Comment: Какая версия прошивки? Покажите скриншот?

Comment: v2.06(AAFS.0)C3